# Does the body of Nikon D750 make clicking sound/noise when moving it up and down?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-basics, noise, body

I just got a brand new Nikon D750 body. However, I found that the package has a lot of room to move around so I don't know if there was any damage done to the camera body during the shipping.

When I move the camera back and forth from pointing the camera upward, then downward, and repeat, I can hear some "ticking/clicking" sound caused by the movement. It sounds to me like some internal part (i.e. a lens/mirror inside the camera body) is kind of loose and have room to move about inside the camera body, and slightly hitting the surrounding (my hypothesis).

It does seem to take pictures fine. So I am curious if other D750 does the same and have the similar noise from movement.

I did try similar to the other two DLSR. Nikon D5000 makes some noise but the noise level is much much fainter. Olympus E520 makes even smaller noise which is almost negligible.

===============================

As an update which may be helpful for future users:

I went to a local camera store, and their D750 also has that slight "thing-shifting-inside-the-camera" sound, he said it's normal so I think I am at ease.

Comment: Is your function or preview button set to aperture preview, and if so, are you accidentally hitting it from the shifting of positions? From my experience on the D7200, these buttons have little to no feedback.

Comment: VR lens by any chance? Does it do it if you take the lens off?

Comment: Yes. It's not from the lens, it comes from the body.

Comment: It is set to manual. The sound persists regardless if the camera is on or off. So I think it's something mechanical from inside the camera body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikon service center in Mumbai (on 10 Nov 16) told me that it is in the diopter adjustment section and it is normal for D750.

Comment: Thank god. I thought mine got damaged. Noticed it only today and got scared. 

Answer (score 1):

My D810 does the same thing, I think it's the latch for the built in flash rattling a little because it doesn't do it when the flash is up. I wouldn't be too worried as long as everything else works fine.